# this.props working for one func and don't work for another React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

My problem is described in the topic

Here it works:

```
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {

    if (name !== this.props.prevName) {
        document.getElementById(name).style = 'border: 3px solid black';
        if (document.getElementById(this.props.prevName))
            document.getElementById(this.props.prevName).style = 'border: 1px solid black';
        this.props.dispatch({type: 'CHANGE_PREVNAME', payload: name});
        let i = this.props.items.findIndex(element => {
            return (element.general.firstName + ' ' + element.general.lastName) === name;
        });
        this.props.dispatch( { type: 'CHANGE_SELECTION', payload: this.props.items[i] } );
    }
}
```

And here it doesn't work:

```
searchHandler(event) {
    this.props.dispatch( { type: 'CHANGE_TERM', payload: event.target.value } );
}
```

It's functions of the same class, and here `mapDispatchToProps` (outside the class ofc) func:

```
 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      ...bindActionCreators({
        toTakeData: loadItems,
        dispatch: dispatch
      }, dispatch)
    };
}
```

Comment: Please add `searchHandler` constructor and connect script

Comment: For the function it is not working, make it an arrow function.

Comment: searchHandler = (event) =>  {
    ...
}
This will work for you

Comment: @AbhayShiro omg, I'm so dumb, thank you a lot!

Comment: we all learn from mistakes mate :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, `this` will be `undefined`
>   when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions
>   work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without `()`
>   after it, such as `onClick={this.handleClick}`, you should bind that
>   method.

If you use babel you can use the [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) which will lead to `this` being bound automatially. Note that this method is still not in the language standard and does only work because babel transforms it to valid javascript:

```
searchHandler = event => { /* this is defined here ... */ }
```

The es5 way would be to bind the function in the `constructor`:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // bind this to your handler
        this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);

        /* other initialization */
    }

    searchHander(event) { /* you can access this here... */ }
}
```

Note that the arrow function syntax comes with some limitations. For example you can't override it in classes that extend the class it was defined in. In react this is not a problem most of the time because [inheritance is discouraged](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) in favour of composition.

Answer (score 0):

For the function it is not working, make it an arrow function

`searchHandler = (event) => { ... }`

Comment: This is called [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/). Note that this does only work, because babel transforms that to valid javascript. It is still not officially in the language standard although it will probably be in the future. The alternative and es5 way would be to bind the function to `this` in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
searchHandler(event) {
    this.props.dispatch( { type: 'CHANGE_TERM', payload: event.target.value } );
}
```

Problem is of "this". "this" for searchHandler is not bound correctly. For handleItemClick function as it is defined as arrow function and arrow function get "this" from where it is defined.